# Telegram modifes every link to redirect to desktop.telegram.org/changelog in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, ubuntu, telegram

On ubuntu,

I used to have `Telegram Desktop` and `Telegram Plugin` for Chrome on Ubuntu.

Then I removed Telegram Desktop and the plugin.

Then I re-installed the chrome browser, removing all browser related settings.

But still when I open a browser the first what I see is this **annoying** link in new tab: https://desktop.telegram.org/changelog

And every time when I click on any link that require opening a browser, what I see instead of the link content is the https://desktop.telegram.org/changelog.

Seems this Telegram Desktop modified more settings than it should. I wonder what else it did that I do not know yet.

Any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

ok. 30 minutes of my life :) :

From the chrome setting itself it is very hard to say what's going on.

So I forgot about these settings.

```
 cd ~/.config
 rm -rf google-chrome/
```

, so removed them.

Hope it could be useful for someone.

But it made my mind not to install the desktop (or web) version of it.

Bad change-log marketing..